# using regexp_replace function with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, regexp-replace

I am trying to use regexp_replace() function with sqlalchemy in sql.execute statement but I could not make it work.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from pandas.io import sql

engine =create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2cffi://...')
sql.execute("""create view test as select name,
regexp_replace(name, '\\s\\(([0-9]+)\\)$', '') as name2
from table""", engine)
```

I guess I need to define a function for it but I am new in python and could not figure out how it works.

Comment: would you mind telling the backend db server? Also what error are you getting?

Comment: Hi, it is amazon redshift server. I am not getting any error, just function does not work. When I run the same query directly in database, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with executing sql with engine?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2cffi://...')
engine.execute("create view test as select name,regexp_replace(name, '\\s\\(([9]+)\\)$', '') as name2
from table")
```